# Hibernate criteria to get a maximum length of the column value

Tags: hibernate

I wonder if it is possible to write a criteria or set a projection to get a maximum result of the string value length? Thanks in advance.
so I try to do like this:

```
    Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(yourClass.class);
    crit.add(Restrictions.eq("propertyName", propertyValue));
    crit.setProjection(Projections.max("anotherPropertyName"));
    Integer maxLength = crit.uniqueResult().toString().length();
```

but unfortunately it gets me not the biggest value!  I don't know why!

Answer (score 0):

Try [SQL Projection](http://srcrr.org/java/hibernate/3.6.2/reference/org/hibernate/criterion/SQLProjection.html) with sql snippet specific to your db.

Comment: sorry but i don't really understand how the **GROUP BY** can help me

Comment: I'll take it back. You probably don't need group by. But SQL Projection is a way to go,I think.

Comment: Yep no doubts, I wonder about how the **max** works with string value. Looks like it miss something!